# How to define ApiQuery dynamically with the keys of a specified entity?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-swagger

I'm struggling with the typing of my query params in NestJs, I have a route like this and I want to be able to filter my result with all the keys of my datamining entities. I did this and it's working but I can't find a way to make it appear in my swagger:

```js
@Controller('datamining')
export class DataminingController {
    @Get('short')
    @ApiQuery({ required: false, type: DataminingShort }) // <== how to type this ? Obviously this one is not working.
    findAll(@Query() options?: Partial<DataminingShort>) { // <== DataminingShort is an entity class for typeOrm
       return this.dataminingShortService.findAll(options);
    }
}
```

I want to avoid doing a specific class just for this since it's exactly the same properties as my typeOrm entity

Comment: What do you mean by "it't not working"? Do you have your `DataminingShort` class decorated with `@nestjs/swagger` annotations?

Comment: I have the nestjs/swagger plugin installed that is supposed to automatically check the class so you don't have to put the nestjs/swagger annotations (It works with other routes). Here the query params are not even showing in the swagger

Comment: @JayMcDoniel What I mean by "it's not working" is that the query params are not displayed in my swagger, I was expecting to have all the properties of my entity DataminingShort displayed so I can filter my query from the swagger. But instead of this it just show nothing

Answer (score 0):

If your `DataminingShort` entity isn't showing up in the docs, it *might* be because your `nest-cli.json` doesn't specify the correct `dtoFileNameSuffix`. I assume your `DataminingShort` is located in a `DataminingShort.entity.ts` but maybe not.

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "@nestjs/swagger",
        "options": {
          "introspectComments": true,
          "dtoFileNameSuffix": [".dto.ts", ".entity.ts"]
        }
      }
    ],
```

Another option might be to add `@ApiExtraModels(DataminingShort)` to your `DataminingController` controller class.